# Can others use fwrite to manipulate files in my domain?

Tags: php, html, security

On the domain that I own, what keeps other coders from other websites from manipulating my pages using a code similar to this?

```
<?php
$fname = 'www.somedomain.com';
$open = fopen($fname, 'w');
$txt = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>...<!--Code goes here-->...</html>";
fwrite($open, $txt);
fclose($open);
?>
```

Comment: It's related to operating system permissions which allows public to access the file in read-only format.

Comment: @MA No it's not.

Comment: If you don't specify a scheme, the parameter to `fopen()` (not `$fopen`, btw) will be interpreted as a regular file, so PHP will try to read a local file named `www.somedomain.com`. If you were to provide a scheme like `http://www.somedomain.com`,  PHP will invoke the [HTTP wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) which will give you **read-only** access to that resource via a HTTP GET request.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen  Are you saying that fopen() will not work with an absolute path, even if it is in the same domain as the code that called it?

Comment: It all depends on the protocol you use. For regular file system access, you're restricted to the permissions set in the file system, and there's no concept of a domain. If you access over HTTP, FTP, SMB, SSH or whatever, you're restricted by whatever the protocol and the service offering the protocol allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean other people that are running their code **on the same server** in some form of shared-host model: operating system file permissions. Every user of the system (that would be *you*) has their own username, and files and directories belong to just that user and are not accessible by other users.

If you mean any other person anywhere else, not even on the same server: the server is only running a web server which only accepts HTTP network requests. You have no access to the file system through an HTTP server. The server simply doesn't expose the capability for you to access any files over the internet.